# force mysqld to use etc hosts for reverse lookup

Tags: mysql, bind, reverse-dns, hosts

I have a server hosted by hetzner running mysqld.
I already setup some "ddns for poor ones" to add my dial-on IP (Telekom) to the server's /etc/hosts. Now all Users in mysql are limited to localhost, but my development machine at home must also connect. When doing so, the mysql deamon does a reverse lookup in DNS, but my (existing and correctly working!) local bind ofcause does not contain (cheated) reverse zones for telekom networks :-/  to resolve my Telekom dialed home network's ip.

Final result: mysql does not let me in, because my DNS reverse name is something.dip0.t-ipconnect.de (and not the poor-DDNS'ed name) and will change from time to time. How can I force the mysqld to use the /etc/hosts for reverse lookup .. or does anyone have a better idea to allow my dial-on network to connect to mysql without opening to % (any)?

^5 & thx

Answer (score 0):

well, the easy solution is: it DOES use the usual order for reverse lookup of the source IPs, I just stumbled across the host cache, that mysql server keeps and that still contained the orginal (dynamic) hostname resolved by my dial-on provider.
After truncating that table, the actual resolution is taken, which includes local /etc/hosts.